# I want to select the icon from the list but it always showing some other icon instead of icon in code point

Tags: list, flutter, fetch

I am trying to get the icon from the list but the code I am entering into the list is not the same I got from the output

```
final List<int> points = <int>[
      0xe5d5,
      58837,
    ];
    final Random r = Random();

    Icon randomIcon() => Icon(
          IconData(points[r.nextInt(points.length)],
              fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons', matchTextDirection: true),
          color: myColor,
        );
    print(r.nextInt(points.length));
```

Comment: I/chatty  (32312): uid=10383(com.flutter.ui_kit) 1.ui identical 1 line
this is showing when i print the output

Comment: Maybe I did not get your question, but you are calling the `r.nextInt()` function twice, there is no guarantee that you will get the same index (it's random, right?), hence you are getting different output.